# Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-singular matrices such that $AA^T=BB^T$. Show that there exist two orthogonal matrices $C,D$ such that $A=BC$ and $B=AD$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-singular matrices such that $AA^T=BB^T$. Show that there exist two orthogonal matrices $C,D$ such that $A=BC$ and $B=AD$.

Attempt

$C,D$ orthogonal matrices so, $CC^T=I=DD^T$. We have to find the expression of  $C,D$ in terms of  $A,B$.

$A=BC$ implies $C=B^{-1}A$, but $CC^T=I\implies (B^{-1}A)(B^{-1}A)^T=I$ i.e $C=B^{-1}A=((B^{-1}A)^T)^{-1}=(A^T\{B^{-1}\}^T)^{-1}=\left(A^T\{B^{T}\}^{-1}\right)^{-1}=B^T(A^T)^{-1}$. Please help me to get the desired answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We note
$$
AA'=BB'\implies A=B(B'(A')^{-1}),\quad AA'=BB'\implies A(A'(B')^{-1})=B
$$
so let's set $C=B'(A')^{-1}$ and $D=A'(B')^{-1}$. $C$ is orthogonal because
$$
C'C=[B'(A')^{-1}]'B'(A')^{-1}=A^{-1}BB'(A')^{-1}=A^{-1}AA'(A')^{-1}=I.
$$
The orthogonality of $D$ can be verified similarly.